# SharePoint 2019 does not display site contents correctly on migrated sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, migration, content-migration

We made our first test migrations for some Content Databases on a SharePoint 2019 Farm.

The migrated sites are working perfectly with one exception. When we go to "Site Contents" the page is not displayed correctly. The App Launcher is missing, some pictures do not load and the Lists of the site are not showed under contents.

When we switch to subsites the page starts to be shown correctly. App Launcher is there, user name gets shown in the top right corner, pictures are loaded and the subsites are listed.

When i then switch back to contents the page is still corretly displayed but the lists still dont show up.

Maybe somebody has an idea on that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What was the source farm version?

Comment: Was SharePoint Server 2013 but we first migrated the databases to 2016 and then to 2019

Comment: Did you upgrade the sites to v15 mode on 2013?

Comment: Yes we upgraded them

Comment: Did you check the UI version?

Comment: UI Version is 15

Comment: When I use the Developer Tools i can see a 404 on the URL https://<...>/_api/web/AppTiles when I'm on the contents tab. This request does not show up when I'm using the working tab Subsites. On sites newly created on SharePoint 2019 i can also see this request in developer tools but on this sites the request gets a 200 and everything is fine.

Comment: I just found out that now the problem also occurs on not migrated sites

Comment: We are experiencing nearly the same behavior on one of our newly migrated customer systems. Modern experience not working (not even on "Subsites"), classic experience shows the contents.
Were you able to sort out what the issue is?